# sforce.console.openPrimaryTab has stopped working after upgrade to API 40.0 (Summer 2017)

Tags: javascript, tab, cti, summer-17

I am developing a salesforce CTI integration that uses Version 37 of the salesforce JavaScript API.

When the user logs into the softPhone view I open another tab using the `sforce.console.openPrimaryTab` function. I have had this functionality working for a long time, but this morning it is not opening the tab, and I haven't changed any code relating to it.

I call the openPrimary tab like this:

```
salesforceApi.console.openPrimaryTab(null, salesforceConfigurationManager.dashboardTabUrl, true, 'Dashboard', myCallback, 'myDashboardTabName');
```

My callback method is never hit.

I can see an error in the console:

```
aura_prod.js:878 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
throws at https://mysalesforceName.cs26.my.salesforce.com/jslibrary/1493309924000/sfdc/main.js:1290:54 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Function.QueryString.getQueryStringIndex (main.js:1290)
at Function.QueryString.getURI (main.js:1290)
at Object.Sfdc.support.servicedesk.isNewEditUrl (ServiceDesk.js:formatted:4256)
at constructor.checkIsLimited (ServiceDesk.js:formatted:13626)
at new constructor (ServiceDesk.js:formatted:13488)
at Object.create (ext.js:formatted:9782)
at constructor.createComponent (ext.js:formatted:11583)
at constructor.lookupComponent (ext.js:formatted:11574)
at constructor.add (ext.js:formatted:11454)
at constructor.replaceTab (ServiceDesk.js:formatted:18607)
```

When I debug the code I can see that the error is occurring when it is checking if the URL of the tab I want to open is allowed (the `checkIsLimited` function on  serviceDesk.js).

[image]

The error is thrown because the contentUrl property of the object that is being passed into the `checkIsLimited` function is undefined.

If I trace back to the beginning of the error stack (the `replaceTab` function), I can see that in here the contentUrl property is also undefined.

[image]

If I set the contentUrl property by setting a break-point in the JavaScript and manually changing the value, the tab will open, so it looks like this is the cause of the issue, however I don't know what is causing contentUrl to be undefined as I have changed nothing in my code

- I have tried logging in with a different user to determine if there is some user setting that could be causing this, but the problem persists.
- I have tried calling the openPrimaryTab with only the required parameters and hard-coded values, the tab still doesn't open.
- I have reverted back to old versions of the code that are currently working in production, the tab still doesn't open.

Any ideas what else I can do. This was working perfectly on Friday and this morning it doesn't work

**EDIT:**
I have just found that the salesforce version has been upgraded to Summer 2017. Should the API calls still not work?

**EDIT:**
Still waiting for salesforce to fix this, but I have noticed that any URL that has less than 2 characters after the domain seems to work. For example `https://<domain>/something` will crash, as will `https://<domain>/som`. However `https://<domain>/so` will work as will `https://<domain>/so/mething`

Comment: I don't *think* this would have any effect, but have you tried the "proper" method of using [sforce.console.generateConsoleUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_generateconsoleurl.htm)? I don't know why this would make a difference, but perhaps you could give it a spin?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have tried using generateConsoleUrl followed by openConsoleUrl and I get the same error.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to open? I have one that is working and one that isn't. The one that isn't looks like https://xyz.com/dashboard. It seems that the word dashboard makes it think it is trying to open a Salesforce dashboard.

Comment: The url doesn't include the word dashboard, also I tried opening a tab with a very short URL in case it was the issue and got the same result. I believe this is a salesforce issue related to the upgrade. I have also tried using the latest API (version 40) but the same thing happens

Comment: I traced it down to an issue with the response from /ui/support/servicedesk/servlet/ServiceDeskServlet Looks like in a summer sandbox, the response is a 200, but in spring, it is 500. I guess this means we should open a case with Salesforce...

Comment: @Neil So, I just spent half the day troubleshooting this, and then I remembered this question was asked. I guess that's what I get for not paying attention...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Summer 17. I've been able to replicate it in a sandbox. After some "fun" debugging it, here's what I found. There is a call to `/ui/support/servicedesk/servlet/ServiceDeskServlet` that is done to determine whether or not to build a workspace. It looks like if the URL is a standard URL, it does something different than if it is a custom URL.

In Spring 17, the response from the server is a `500`, but in Summer 17, it is a 200. This is causing the Javascript to take different branches.

Spring 17
[image: Spring 17 Response]

Summer 17
[image: Summer 17 Response]

I'm going to open a case with Salesforce on this and would recommend you do the same.

Edit: Response from support: "I have followed the information you have provided, investigated on the same in your sandbox org. I also recreated and tested in the Spring sandbox. This definitely seems to be release related issue. I have already escalated this issue to my tier 3 team."

Edit 2: A known Issue has been created. I've been told it will be patched in a few days: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008k7xQAA

Comment: I don't suppose you'd mind sharing that case #? I also have the same problem and need to get it resolved. We're not able to do testing in our sandbox because of this.

Comment: Case number 16450627

Comment: Thanks. By the way, did you happen to have a # in your URL? That seems to be part of the cause.

Comment: For me, the one that works has a # in the url. The two I was testing with are external servers.